# How to detect JS updated ColumnDataSource by Python in Bokeh?

Tags: python, bokeh

In Bokeh, I have a `CustomJS` triggering a callback updating a `ColumnDataSource`. I would like to have any update to this trigger some Python code. However, this does not work by specifying an `on_change` callback to the data source nor can I access the updated data. What am I doing wrong? My code...

```
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, CustomJS, Button
from bokeh.layouts import layout
from bokeh.tile_providers import get_provider
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.events import Tap


def callback():
    print('button checks source:')
    print(source.data)


def callback_source(attr, old, new):
    print('source changed!')
    print(source.data)


# define the source, initially empty
source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(lon=[], lat=[]))

# set a map
tile_provider = get_provider('CARTODBPOSITRON')
initial_bounds = ((-1000000, 4000000), (3000000, 8000000))
plot = figure(
    x_range=initial_bounds[0], y_range=initial_bounds[1],
    x_axis_type="mercator", y_axis_type="mercator"
)
plot.add_tile(tile_provider)

# show the current lon/lat pair in source
plot.circle(x="lon", y="lat", size=15, fill_alpha=0.8, source=source)
plot.js_on_event(Tap, CustomJS(args=dict(source=source), code="""
    // get the source.data contents
    const x = source.data['lon'];
    const y = source.data['lat'];
    // if source.data is empty, append the cursor coords
    if (x.length == 0) {
        x.push(cb_obj.x);
        y.push(cb_obj.y);
    // if source.data is populated, replace the cursor coords
    } else {
        x[0] = cb_obj.x;
        y[0] = cb_obj.y;
    }
    source.change.emit();
"""))
# how to detect changes in source.data which trigger Python code?
source.on_change('data', callback_source)
button = Button(label="show source.data status", button_type="success")
# print the source status
button.on_click(callback)
curdoc().add_root(layout([button, plot]))
```

leads to a plot, where my Tap Events are correctly updating the circle, but apparently not updating the `source` variable.

```
2022-01-07 08:12:46,924 Starting Bokeh server version 2.4.2 (running on Tornado 6.1)
2022-01-07 08:12:46,927 User authentication hooks NOT provided (default user enabled)
2022-01-07 08:12:46,931 Bokeh app running at: http://localhost:5006/temp_test
2022-01-07 08:12:46,931 Starting Bokeh server with process id: 4797
2022-01-07 08:12:48,212 WebSocket connection opened
2022-01-07 08:12:48,214 ServerConnection created
button checks source:
{'lon': [], 'lat': []}
```

Based on the answer provided by @bigreddot, the following new JS code (`source.change.emit()` is not necessary) works:

```
    const x=[cb_obj.x];
    const y=[cb_obj.y];
    const new_data = {lon:x, lat:y};
    source.data = new_data;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a property update event sent back to Python you will have to actually assign an entire new ("dict") value to `source.data`, and not just update the arrays "in place". The call to `source.change.emit()` is purely a JS-side event and has no effect whatsoever on the Python side.

Comment: Thank you! Could you please elaborate a bit more? Can I have the property update event formulated inside the `js_on_event` code? My use case is, show map, user selects location interactively in map, location is used to update multiple other models.

Comment: You need to have a line that ls literally equivalent to `source.data = some_new_object` in your JS callback.